# Help needed for old links to www.iphonesdkarticles.com

Tags: discussion, status-completed, broken-link

http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com is dead and [archive.org doesn't have it due to a robots.txt](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/).

But we have <s>[198](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=www.iphonesdkarticles.com)</s> [1 post left with a dead link to iphonesdkarticles.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Awww.iphonesdkarticles.com), from Jan 2009 to May 2013.

**What to do?**

Comment: What is the help you are asking for? Deleting/flagging as link only (if link only). Editing out the outdated links for answers that have some value without the link? If so in what way?

Comment: Holy *crap*, there's a lot of stuff in those links that should be incinerated...

Comment: @Cœur Clarification is what I asked for. I don't want to start flagging when you have a better solution.

Comment: FYI 49 of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=www.iphonesdkarticles.com+is%3Aquestion) are in questions

Comment: @suraj That makes at some of them ripe for closing as "Unclear what you asking". Unfortunately that leaves the in the search results for a while longer

Comment: @Anthon  yeah or "No MCVE" if all details are not in the question itself..

Comment: I think I have seen every post with links to that website. I have flagged, delete, close and/or down voted every post where appropriate. I removed the link from posts where it made sense but I didn't touch posts where others already left a comment. We might need a few 3K users to go over the still open questions and cast close votes if needed. Most of them will then be roomba-ed. The same is true for answers with delete votes but that need 20K-ers. The list is down to 20 posts so it wouldn't take too long for anyone to visit those posts.

Comment: Bah, some I already visited and are waiting for roomba...

Comment: @Cœur Back down to 0 again. I've rolled back to your second revision on that final question as OP has now seen my comment but has not removed the link themselves. I'll modflag if OP restores the link again.

Comment: @Cœur It's been 3 days since I made the second rollback, and OP hasn't restored the original version, so I'd say that's now mission accomplished.

Comment: @MichaelDodd that current Meta question already got its [meta-tag:status-completed]. ;)

Answer (score 39):

**Every single link-only answer, regardless of whether or not the link is broken, should be flagged as "not an answer".**

To add to this, any answer that doesn't incorporate the key parts from that now defunct site should be flagged as such as well.

This is why we flag these questions.  Now that the site's gone, their answer is worthless.

Comment: Also, some of these resource request questions are duplicate targets for even more resource request questions. Should we go and try to delete those questions too?

Comment: @AndrewLi that makes sense yes. Might be worth to close questions first, so they can be deleted, either by roomba or delete votes.

Comment: @andrew if you can come up with a list of them in a gist, send them to me. I'll try to hammer close them if warranted. (So that you can save your close votes)

Comment: @rene while deleting them, if you feel that any of them need a histolock, ping me.

Comment: @BhargavRao Okay, will do.

Comment: @BhargavRao Was a bit of a dummy and wasted some close votes. I'm not able to right now but I can tomorrow. Also -- is it worth flagging answers with NAA? I was thinking just deleting the questions would be faster.

Comment: @BhargavRao here is my first revision of a  [gist](https://gist.github.com/rschrieken/4641aa50e3957c92c12da97555534a37) with close worthy questions.

Comment: @AndrewLi technically speaking, we *shouldn't* be (according to Shog's apple post), but the advantage is that if all the answers of a post are deleted, then it'll roomba faster. It'd certainly add to the lqpq (which was brought down yesterday after some effort), so I guess we'd rather not flag them. But if it's a link only answer, then flagging is also appropriate as Makato says in their answer.

Comment: @rene Went through them, deleted the link only ones, and closed those that were too obvious. (left a couple of ones)

Comment: "_You can only flag for moderator attention 18 times per day_". Well, I'm out of flags for now. I'll continue to flag tomorrow.

Comment: @Cœur You don't need to flag every single one of them. You already posted a Meta question. Edit the links into the question, or do like Bhargav already suggested and put them in a gist.

Comment: @BhargavRao I've updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/rschrieken/4641aa50e3957c92c12da97555534a37) with 5 new links to questions that are possbile close worthy.

Comment: Thank you @rene. Mission accomplished (well, only 1 link left)

Comment: @Cœur Given that last remaining post was a rollback by OP, I've left a comment advising about this meta discussion. Rest of the answer looks ok (or at the very least would survive the LQP queue), so let's see if OP voluntarily restores your revision.